# Output from ls has newlines but displays on a single line. Why?

Tags: bash, terminal, ls, od

I think I may be overlooking a relatively fundamental point regarding shell. Output from the **ls** command by default separates output with newlines, but the shell displays the output on a single line.

Can anyone explain this to me? I had always presumed that the output was simply separated by spaces, but now that I see the output separated by newlines, I would expect the output to be displaying on separate lines.

Example:

```
cpoweradm@debian:~/lpi103-4$ ls text*
text1  text2  text3
```

**od** shows that the output is separated by newlines:

```
cpoweradm@debian:~/lpi103-4$ ls text* | od -c
0000000   t   e   x   t   1  \n   t   e   x   t   2  \n   t   e   x   t
0000020   3  \n
0000022
```

If newlines are present, then why doesn't the output display as:

```
text1 
text2
text3
```

Comment: And that's why `ls | wc -l` returns the number of files and folders.

Comment: If you find that behavior wicked, you're in good company: [Pike and Kernighan disapprove that oddity of Ls](http://harmful.cat-v.org/cat-v/unix_prog_design.pdf) (see `lsc` on page 5).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

When you pipe the output, `ls` acts differently.

This fact is hidden away in the [info documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html#ls-invocation):

> If standard output is a terminal, the output is in columns (sorted vertically) and control characters are output as question marks; otherwise, the output is listed one per line and control characters are output as-is.

To prove it, try running

```
ls
```

and then

```
ls | less
```

This means that if you want the output to be guaranteed to be one file per line, regardless of whether it is being piped or redirected, you have to run

```
ls -1
```

(`-1` is the number one)

Or, you can force `ls | less` to output in columns by running

```
ls -C
```

(`-C` is a capital C)

Comment: So it does... Sneaky. Is this a general principle in UNIX that can be summarized succinctly or rather an implementation detail specific to ls?

Comment: @theconnorpower: it's pretty much specific to `ls`.  It is useful, but is clearly inconsistent and surprising.  But note that some commands that produce colored output will strip the colors out when being piped too.

Comment: @theconnorpower: Trivia: The inventors of Unix went on to write Plan9.  In Plan9, `ls` always prints one per line, and `lc` always prints in columns.

Comment: @theconnorpower: There are also programs that read the size of the terminal, and adjust their output accordingly, for example on Debian `dpkg -l` will use the whole width of the screen, but if it's printing to a pipe, it assumes the terminal is 80 columns wide, and abbreviates the output to make it fit if necessary.

Comment: @Mikel Interesting to hear the ls/lc differences in Plan9. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @Mikel Of course, you can always create some aliases, using the mentioned options, to mimic the plan 9 behaviour. @theconnorpower Many of these are GNU tools enhancements.

Comment: How can a program determine if its output is redirected to a file or whether it is going to a shell?

Comment: I find with -C I also need to use -w <width> because some times my file names at too large for the default size

Comment: Here is the explanation of `-1` flag of `ls` from `man`: Force output to be one entry per line.  This is the default when output is not to a terminal.

Answer (score 11):

Your discovery highlights the primary reason why parsing the output of `ls` is always a bad idea. See Greg's wiki for a [full explanation](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Think of your problem in reverse. You noticed that ls sometimes does and sometimes doesn't print newlines between it's output. For use in scripts or when forced by the `-1` flag, it does. One newline at the end of each file. What there is **no guarantee that each newline represents a new file name**. In fact, if a filename contains a newline itself, the output of ls will be absolutly un-parsable. Consider these filenames:

```
file1
file2\nfile3
file4
```

When you `ls -1` a directory with that in it, you would get something that looked like this:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

Would you not naturally asume there were four files? So would any scripts that parse the output of ls. In reality there are three files, one of the with a tricky name, but you would not be able to figure that out from the output of ls.*

<sub>* Unless you were using the `-l` flag and noticed the output was borked, but your scripts would still choke.</sub>

Comment: If you *really* have to parse the output of `ls`, the `-b` option can help.  It turns the newline into `\n`, etc.

Comment: You say parsing it is a bad idea. Any alternatives?

Comment: @Bluu Use shell globbing, or `find -exec`, or tell whatever you are using to use null terminators instead of newlines (many tools other than `ls` support this), or any of dozens of other options. There is tons written on this already or ask a specific question about what's needed.