# How to list *.tar.gz, one filename per line?

Tags: ls

I am trying to list every `.tar.gz` file, only using the following command:

`ls *.tar.gz -l`

...It shows me the following list:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 osm osm  949 Nov 27 16:17 file1.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 osm osm  949 Nov 27 16:17 file2.tar.gz
```

However, I just need to list it this way:

```
file1.tar.gz 
file2.tar.gz
```

and also not:

```
file1.tar.gz file2.tar.gz
```

How is this "properly" done?

Comment: it is a good habit to use options before filenames. and you need to use -1 instead of -l

Comment: `ls -1 *.tar.gz`, but what do you want to use the list _for_?  If you are doing something to those filenames, then `ls` is not the right way to do it. See [Why \*not\* parse \`ls\` (and what do to instead)?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985)

Comment: the manual you need is `man ls`. Ensure that your display font has good contrast between 1 (one) and l (lower case letter ell).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output from ls has newlines but displays on a single line. Why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/output-from-ls-has-newlines-but-displays-on-a-single-line-why)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `-1` option (the digit “one”, not lower-case “L”) will list one file per line with no other information:

```
ls -1 -- *.tar.gz
```

Comment: Why the double dashes? `ls -1 *.tar.gz` works just as well.

Comment: @RonJohn it avoids surprises with filenames starting with `-`.

Comment: Specifically... Say I was an attacker, and had the following files: `.hiddenfile`, `benign.php`, `evil.bin`, `--hide=*evil*`; without the `--` you won't see `evil.bin` _or_ `--hide=*evil*`.

Comment: I'm utterly disppointed that there is no `-2` (or -3 etc.)! ;-)

Comment: (... which made me look up `columns`!)

Answer (score 19):

If you only need the filenames, you could use `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' *.tar.gz
```

... the shell will expand the `*.tar.gz` wildcard to the filenames, then `printf` will print them, with each followed by a newline. This output would differ a bit from [that of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484482/117549) in the case of filenames with newlines embedded in them:

## setup

```
$ touch file{1,2}.tar.gz
$ touch file$'\n'3.tar.gz
```

## ls

```
$ ls -1 -- *.tar.gz
file1.tar.gz
file2.tar.gz
file?3.tar.gz
```

## printf

```
$ printf '%s\n' *.tar.gz
file1.tar.gz
file2.tar.gz
file
3.tar.gz
```

Comment: See also `ls -b`, `ls -Q`, ls `--quoting-style=...`.

Comment: And `printf '%q\n'`. (Both GNU.)

Answer (score 9):

`ls` behaves differently when its output is piped.  For example:

```
ls          # outputs filenames in columns
ls | cat    # passes one filename per line to the cat command
```

So if you want see all your `*.tar.gz` files, one per line, you can do this:

```
ls *.tar.gz | cat
```

But what if you *don't* want to pipe your output?  That is, is there a way to force `ls` to output the filenames one to a line without piping the output?

Yes, with the `-1` switch.  (That's a dash with the number 1.)  So you can use these commands:

```
ls -1             # shows all (non-hidden) files, one per line
ls -1 *.tar.gz    # shows only *.tar.gz files, one per line
```

Answer (score 7):

Or with `GNU find`:

```
find  -name "*.tar.gz"  -printf '%P\n'
```

In contrary to `ls` with `*` it will search for `.tar.gz` files recursively:

```
$ find  -name "*.tar.gz"  -printf '%P\n'
file1.tar.gz
dir/file3.tar.gz
file2.tar.gz
```

Comment: Why `-printf '%P\n'` rather than just `-print` - at which point any Posix compatible `find` will work.

Comment: @MartinBonner because `-print` will add `./` before the filename.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly more roundabout and *loopy* way:

```
for i in *.tar.gz; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

EDIT: added quotes to handle weird filenames

Comment: `touch -- '-e \a.tar.gz'` for a reason to quote your variables and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/117549 for reasons to use printf instead of echo

Comment: oof, I just spent 5 minutes trying to figure out how to remove the resulting `-e \a.tar.gz` file

Comment: sorry! `rm -- '-e \a.tar.gz'` should do the trick

Comment: You're good, it was a lesson, and I did learn that `--` works for `rm` and a lot of others.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: the other solution for local names is `rm_etc './-x blah'`