# echo strings but extra question mark was added to the output

Tags: cat, echo, special-characters

Strange "?" got added to the filename output.

```
SCRIPTS="/path_to_script/"
SUMMER=`cat /path_to_file/summer.txt`

for i in ${SUMMER};
  do cat <<- EOF > $SCRIPTS/20190430_$(echo ${i})_step4.r
#content omit
EOF
   done
```

Expected ourput would be

```
20190430_spring1_step4.r
20190430_spring2_step4.r
20190430_summer1_step4.r
20190430_summer2_step4.r
```

But I got the question mark after each variable except the last row from the `${SUMMER}`.

```
20190430_spring1?_step4.r
20190430_spring2?_step4.r
20190430_summer1?_step4.r
20190430_summer2_step4.r
```

What is the problem? 
`${SUMMER}`is a txt file with only one column

Comment: Question mark (`?`), or dollar (`$`)?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I updated the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file contains [CR+LF (DOS/Windows style) line endings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation). These question marks are just [`ls` denoting CR characters that survived](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10422/108618). CR characters are literally in the names of the files. The last name is OK probably because the last line in the file has no line ending at all.

To confirm this invoke `file /path_to_file/summer.txt`. I guess the tool will tell you about "CRLF line terminators".

Use `dos2unix` to convert the file to Unix format first.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I will install dos2unix first and see if that works. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. No more odd question marks in the filenames.

Comment: Note that the question marks were never part of the filenames. It is how `ls` shows non-printable characters.  The non-printable character was a carriage return character.