# why does the output of `ls` look different when piped through ``tr "\n" "\n"`?

Tags: bash, ls, tr

The man page for `tr(1)` says:

```
       tr - translate or delete characters

SYNOPSIS
       tr [OPTION]... SET1 [SET2]

DESCRIPTION
       Translate, squeeze, and/or delete characters from standard input, writing to standard output.
```

So as far as I can tell, that means that it takes "\n" and then replaces it with "\n" [which means nothing gets changed].

But that does not explain why doing `ls | tr '\n' '\n'` has the following effect:

```
 $ ls 
 Documents   Downloads   Git   Music   Pictures  '#recycle'   Videos
2019-Dec-24 07:28:44 PM modernNeo:modernNeo-debian/home/modernNeo
 $ ls | tr "\n" "\n"
Documents
Downloads
Git
Music
Pictures
#recycle
Videos
```

Comment: Because `ls` works diferently when feeding a pipe.

Comment: can you elaborate please?

Comment: In fact `echo "abcd" | tr "\n" "\n"` -> `abcd`

Comment: Related: [Output from ls has newlines but displays on a single line. Why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/output-from-ls-has-newlines-but-displays-on-a-single-line-why)

Comment: Try `ls | cat`.

Comment: I see now. i thought it was because `tr` was doing something funny but it is `ls` which is behaving oddly. thanks all

Comment: It doesn't matter if the output of `ls` is a pipe or some other kind of file, but if the output is a tty (terminal) or some other kind of file. If you want `ls` to display files in columns even when piped to `tr` or redirected to a regular file, use the `-C` flag: `ls -C | tr '\n' '\n'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of the `ls` utility may differ depending on whether the output is being written directly to a terminal, or to a pipe.

You will get the same behaviour as with `tr '\n' \n'` if you use `cat`:

```
$ ls
file-00 file-01 file-02 file-03 file-04 file-05 file-06 file-07 file-08 file-09
```

```
$ ls | cat
file-00
file-01
file-02
file-03
file-04
file-05
file-06
file-07
file-08
file-09
```

This behaviour, listing one file per line, is the default output of `ls` described by [the POSIX standard for this utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html):

> **The default format shall be to list one entry per line to standard output**; the exceptions are to terminals or when one of the `-C`, `-m`, or `-x` options is specified. If the output is to a terminal, the format is implementation-defined.

You will also notice the single quotes around your `#recycle` filename "disappearing" when the output is filtered through a pipe.  In fact, these were never part of the filename, but just the way GNU `ls` decided to render the name when outputting it to a terminal (based on what characters the name contains; the `#` is considered "special").  The single quoted name and the output in columns is an "implementation-defined format" permitted by the standard when the output is going to terminal.

Replacing the pipe with a redirection to a file (or to a process substitution in shells that supports these) would also make `ls` format its output in the "default format", with each filename delimited by a newline character.