# Why does echo `ls -l` does not have newlines?

Tags: ls, quoting, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am running WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) and when I use the `ls -l` function on the terminal, I get new lines printed i.e. each file is on a new line e.g.:

```
total 12K
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4.0K Apr  4 23:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 user user 4.0K Apr  4 23:28 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user    0 Mar 28 01:03 a1.file
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 4.5K Mar 23 16:27 books.xml
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user    0 Mar 13 00:19 file1
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user  513 Mar 13 00:19 file2.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 2.8K Mar 13 12:42 file3.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user  405 Apr  4 23:26 ls_l.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user    0 Apr  4 23:28 ls_l2.txt
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user   89 Mar 13 00:18 pattern
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user user   86 Mar 28 01:41 somefile.file
```

However, when I use `` echo `ls -l` > file1.txt ``, it has the same thing as `ls -l` normally but all in one line, where each line is separated by spaces and not new lines e.g.:

```
total 12K drwxrwxrwx 1 user user 4.0K Mar 27 22:45 . drwxr-xr-x 1 user user 4.0K Mar 27 22:45 .. -rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 4.5K Mar 23 16:27 books.xml -rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 0 Mar 13 00:19 file1 -rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 513 Mar 13 00:19 file2.txt -rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 2.8K Mar 13 12:42 file3.txt -rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 403 Mar 27 22:45 ls_l.txt -rw-rw-rw- 1 user user 89 Mar 13 00:18 pattern
```

Note that I have these relevant aliases:

```
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls -lah'
```

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with lines needing to end in CR NL in windows. Are you using some Windows text editor to look at the file ? Which one?

Comment: Nope, I am using `vim` in the terminal.

Comment: I forgot how I somehow got `ls -l > a1.file` to be put in file with only one line. I think I may have piped something (as an issue seen here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10421/output-from-ls-has-newlines-but-displays-on-a-single-line-why) but I still don't know how I would pipe output from `ls -l` to be put in a file. Is that even possible?

Comment: It is difficult to help you if you can not reproduce the problem nor remember what you did to get into the problem in the first place. I don't know what to recommend.

Comment: Oh yes, I remember now. It is because I used ```echo `ls -l` > file1.txt```. Why does it put it on one line only?

Comment: Sorry but the command `echo ls -l | file1.txt` won't provide a list of files, nor write to `file1.txt` and in fact it is a syntax error in any shell. Maybe your memory is playing tricks with you?

Comment: @Isaac Sorry, fixed!

Comment: Nope,  ```. `ls -l` > file1.txt``` should not work either in most cases (unless the first file listed in the present directory is the name of an executable, and, in this case, must be named `ls -l`). Are you sure that that is the question you want answered?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You first code in your comment is not what I have in my previous comment. I have: ```echo `ls -l` > file1.txt```.

Comment: Sorry, misread yor comment, question answered as asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting !!

When you execute `ls -l`, yes, it generates newlines (as you report). When you do `` echo `ls -l` , `` however there are no newlines to be seen. Try it.

The reason is that a `` `...` `` construct is a command expansion, and most expansions (there are others) are affected by shell splitting (when not quoted). Shell splitting removes any of the characters in the variable `IFS`, which, by default, contains `<space><tab><newline>`. All newlines from `ls -l` get removed and the string gets split at that point. Latter, `echo` gets to join each split part separating them with a single space.

So, yes, both, the old, and the correct and preferred at any time new one:

```
echo `ls -l`
echo $(ls -l)
```

Will list files in the current directory in one string without newlines if IFS is default.

Redirecting that string to a file, will write one string to that file, as should be expected.

```
echo $(ls -l) > file
```

To retain the newlines quote the expansion:

```
echo "$(ls -l)"
```

Or, please avoid using the deprecated `` `...` ``:

```
echo "`ls -l`"
```

And to get the output in a file, just redirect it to the file:

```
echo "$(ls -l)" > file
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, I get it now! Also, did you mean "which by default contains 'a space'"?

Comment: @user12055579 Grrr ... Thanks, fixed now.

Comment: @user12055579 Note: [What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)`?](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)